# Store CSS font-size/line-height in Sass variable

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to store the font-size/line-height in a [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) variable like this:

```
$font-normal: 14px/21px;
```

Using this declaration I get a [division](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division_and_) as described in the documentation. Is there a way to avoid the division?
**Note**: I use the scss syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

according to the SCSS reference in http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division_and_slash that is precisely what is expected. try putting it into a mixin:

```
@mixin fontandline{
  font: 14px/12px;
}
```

then, whenever you need to use it again, just write it like that:

```
@include fontandline;
```

see http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins for more information.

EDIT:
according to latest documentation (see link above) the following code

```
p {
  $font-size: 12px;
  $line-height: 30px;
  font: #{$font-size}/#{$line-height};
}
```

should be compiled to

```
p {
  font: 12px/30px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's precisely what is expected. But the doc also states "font: 10px/8px; // Plain CSS, no division". So I thought that it's possible to store this value in a variable and let sass know that it's a plain CSS declaration.
The strange thing is, that this is working without division: "$font-normal: 14px/21px Arial, sans-serif;"
But anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: see the updated documentation. you are now able to do it with # signs. http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash

Answer (score 1):

I use:`$somevar: unquote("14px/17px");`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @capi-etheriel 's answer:

add this to the top of the scss file:

```
@use "sass:list";
```

and than define $font-normal as:

```
$font-normal: list.slash(14px, 21px);
```

For `font:`  to work you have to add at minimum a font-family:

```
p {
  font: $font-normal sans-serif;
}
```

But I assume you realized that.

This will generate in css:

```
p: 14px/21px sans-serif;
```